# URL ID and SEO to separate with regex?

Tags: regex, url, seo

```
<match url="^bilgi/([0-9])-([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
```

1. `http://example.com/bilgi/30-content/` = no problem
2. `http://example.com/bilgi/30-content-new/` = problem

Request Id 1. = 30 Ok
Request Id 2. = 30-content False

How do I edit the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you're trying to match a single digit `[0-9]` in your regex.

Try this instead:

```
^bilgi/([0-9]+)-([_0-9a-z-]+)/
```